# Cross-thread visibility of changes to std::vector synchronized only with Win32 events

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, concurrency, memory-model

Suppose I have a `std::vector<Item>` class member variable where `Item` is some class with getters and setters.
It is created in one thread (#1) but is filled from the other thread (#2) with `push_back`s. In the end it is read in the thread #1. The access to it is synchronized only with Windows [event objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/event-objects). The event is set to a signaled state when the vector is filled up.

Should I beware of cross-thread visibility issues (getting stale values) in this scenario? If yes, how could these issues be prevented?

Comment: How #1 is going to operate on the array? Fill the vector once and forever? Or is it going to add items in a second time? If this is the case you will also need locks, events are not enough.

Comment: @AndreaRossini #1 just creates the vector, then runs #2 and after it's done (i.e. the event is signaled) just reads the result.

Comment: If I understand correctly and thread #2 stops accessing the vector (or stops execution entirely) after the event is signaled, you do not need further synchronization.

Comment: Perhaps you could make a [mcve]. It's not obvious why this is threaded at all since you are doing two things in a serialized manner.

Comment: Events are more for notifications. If I don't use your events but have access to your binaries, I guess I can mess things up. There are lots of other synchronization objects in Windows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/about-synchronization. "Critical Sections" are often used to synchronize access to member state.

Comment: Yes, it can be enough, but it's impossible to tell whether you're doing it right from the amount of info you provide. Consider using futures/promises, they seem to match what I guess you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft says waiting on event objects is enough.

According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/synchronization-and-multiprocessor-issues#memory-ordering):

> The following synchronization functions use the appropriate barriers to ensure memory ordering:
>
> - Functions that enter or leave critical sections
> - Functions that signal synchronization objects
> - Wait functions
> - Interlocked functions

This means if Thread #1 sees the side effect of the event object signaled, it must see the side effect of Thread #2's modification of the vector.

Answer (score 0):

If thread #1 only reads after #2 signals, and #2 doesn't write any new members after it signals, then you have nothing to worry about.

Otherwise, if it's possible for reads and writes to happen at the same time, you don't have visibility problems, **but you have synchronization problems**. std::vector is not a threadsafe data structure, so it can be corrupted if two threads access it at once. Either switch to a different, thread-safe data structure, or surround your vector access with exclusive locks. For standard solutions, look at std::mutex.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to use standard synchronization primitives when possible.

You need to lock once, until vector is filled. E.g. thread#2 will be waiting until thread#1 is done.

```
using Item = int;
std::vector<Item> items;
std::mutex mutex;

// #1
auto t1 = std::thread([&items, &mutex](){
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
  // fill in items...
  // ...
});

// #2
auto t2 = std::thread([&items, &mutex](){
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
  // read...
});

// wait...
t1.join();
t2.join();
```

Comment: You have zero guarantee that `t2` wouldn't get a lock on `mutex` _before_ `t1`.